# For every two in twig

Tags: twig

Is there a way in twig to have a for every two loop? The best way I know to explain what I mean is to show you the result I'm looking for.

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Is there some way to automatically put two items in a row div, and repeat that for as many items as are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet differs from what you are writing below it but I think this is what you want:

```
{% set columns = 2 %}
<div class="row">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="item">{{ item }}</div>
        {% if loop.index % columns %}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll have to test it a bit more to make sure it works right, but I think that's it. Makes sense to me.

Comment: Another way is the `even` test : `{% if loop.index is even %}`

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked great. I did switch the position of the item and if loop for when there's an odd number of items. Doing that keeps two items on the top row, even with an odd number of items.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be to use the [batch](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) function in Twig which does exactly what you want.

Here is the code for your example:

```
{% for row in items|batch(2) %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in row %}
            <div class="item">{{ item }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the suggestions from Markus Kottländer and DarkBee combined:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="item">{{ item }}</div>
        {% if loop.index is even %}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```